# Keep wifi connected on Android Wear

Tags: android, wifi, wear-os, communication, wifimanager

The problem:
I have a Huawei Watch with Android Wear 2.0 . My app should send data over WiFi, but the watch disconnects from the Wifi very fast. How can I keep the watch connected to the Wifi?

Manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

In the activity:

```
public static void keepWiFiOn(Context context, boolean on) {
    if (wifiLock == null) {
        WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wm != null) {
            wifiLock = wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, TAG);
            wifiLock.setReferenceCounted(true);
        }
    }
    if (wifiLock != null) { // May be null if wm is null
        if (on) {
            wifiLock.acquire();
            Log.d(TAG, "Acquired WiFi lock");
        } else if (wifiLock.isHeld()) {
            wifiLock.release();
            Log.d(TAG, "Released WiFi lock");
        }
    }
}
```

The WiFi lock is acquired, but the data is sends isn't received on the other side nevertheless.

Comment: are there any error logs that could give hint why it's disconnecting?

Comment: @noogui Unfortunately not. When I connect to the wifi in the settings menu and it is connected, I launch the app and quit the app to return to the settings screen, then the wifi turns out to be disconnected

Comment: ever find a solution to this?
i have the same issue. wear os 2.0+ device will not reliably take or keep wifi connection when paired with bluetooth phone... and getting a wifi lock doesnt seem to help much

Answer (score 2):

You should request wifi on by ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork

Example code:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = context.getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class);
NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
   .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
   .build();
networkCallback = new NetworkCallback();
cm.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to prevent such 'battery save' behaviour in the preferences of the device.
In this case you case enable this mode in the preferences and disable the connection between wearable and handheld (e.g., disable bluetooth).

This is not possible to do this using your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try disconnecting the Bluetooth connection to your phone.

I found that if they are connected (HuaweiWatch2<->iPhone), the watch will use the phones connection. And it will disregard any locks and reconnect attempts.